# Posit number systems

Tags: floating-point, hpc

I had been studying the **limitations of floating point** numbers and learnt about the "loss of precision" that our algorithms suffer due to the use of floating point numbers. Then I learnt about the Posit Number System which comes as an alternative. It is said to have more precision and more efficiency than floats. But I haven't been able to understand how it has been formulated. There is not much material on the internet that could teach me easily.

Can anyone help me understand the basic concept behind the Posit Number System?

Comment: Here's a good blog post about it: https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2018/04/11/anatomy-of-a-posit-number/

Comment: "It is said to have more precision and more efficiency than floats" --> for some values: yes more precise, for others: no, less precise.   No matter how you cut it, a fixed sized `n` bit _floating point_ type can only represent about 2^n different values.  You still have "loss of precision" issues.  Good luck.  [Posit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unum_(number_format)#Posit)